# Setting active section after redirect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, redirect, triggers

I'm building a personal one-page HTML template with different sections like about me, resume, portfolio, etc.
The theme is using a navigation structure as followed:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#Resume">Resume</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#Blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Needless to say, on each click on the menu items, the page moves to the respective section in the current document.

However, I decided to create a separate HTML file for blog posts named `single-post.html` which uses the exact same structure for navigation.

So, what I wanted to do next, was to redirect the user back to `index.html` and move them to the selected section when they clicked on any menu item. In other words, if the user is viewing `single-post.html` and clicks on `<a class="nav-link" href="#Resume">Resume</a>` they are moved to `index.html` or the main page of the theme, and immediately to the resume section.

This is how I tried to do that using the `trigger()` in jQuery:

```
$('.single .nav-link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var pageID = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
    var selectedPage = pageID[1];
    
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
    
    $('.nav-link[href="#'+ selectedPage +'"]').trigger('click');
});
```

**Note:** The class `single` is assigned to `<body>` of the `single-post.html`.

The code redirects the user to the index file eventually, but that selected section will not have `active` status.

I appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write code in `post.html` to be ran in `index.html`... And whatever you have after `window.location.href = 'index.html';` won't be seen because the browser is loading the `index.html`.

But what you want to do is quite easy because you already have the anchors.

You know a click on the anchor `<a class="nav-link" href="#Resume">Resume</a>` is positionning the page to the element having the `Resume` id...

The same thing can be done by adding `#Resume` straight in the address bar when `index.html` is loaded.
   *(If you didn't know... Try it)*.

So if you follow me...

In the `post.html` page, that will do exactly what you want:

```
window.location.href = 'index.html' + $(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: So what you're proposing is sort of a query string solution, to pass a variable to another page. I had that in mind. But didn't use it, because I didn't want to display the ```href``` of the link on address bar. Is there another way to achieve what I want to do here, or is it the only solution?

Comment: That href appears in the address bar anyway when you just click on the links in your nav... You really didn't notice it before?

Comment: No it does not. I prevent it from appearing on address bar by adding ```event.preventDefault();``` to the click function.

Comment: Okay then... That was the simple solution. But you can look for localStorage then. This [other answer I rencently made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759324/jquery-click-function-with-localstorage-not-working/65769918#65769918) could be an example. After retreiving the href value, you just would have to scroll to the right div.